# How to make the style of subsection and subsubsection identical?

Tags: sectioning

I'm observing a strange behavior in the subsection/subsubsection titles. Their styles look different. Is there a simple way to fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "number size"?

Comment: The size of the subsection number vs the size of the subsubsection number.

Comment: @user: I have edited your question, now does it reflect what you wanted to say? Don't forget to remove your unnecessary comments above.

Comment: Yes, xport, thank you! I was more concerned about the numbers having different height, but this is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this makes the `\subsubsection` looks like a `\subsection`

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\makeatletter
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \normalparindent{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```